# Month Calendar fetching wrong date?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have the user select a date on a month calendar and then display it in the format `yyyymmdd`. Currently I am trying to do it like this:

```
string date = completionCalendar.SelectionEnd.ToString("yyyymmdd");
```

However the issue I'm having is that when I run this I either get 00 as the month or 59 and I'm not sure what I've done wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you visit the docs, you can clearly see that mm is for minutes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

use `MM` for Month:

```
  string date = completionCalendar.SelectionEnd.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Oh this fixed it thank you, is this because lowercase mm is minute?

Answer (score 0):

`"m"` is the format for minutes. `"M"` is for months.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)